# Is it possible to pass the scroll event to the right nested UIScrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have two horizontal UIScrollViews with PagingEnabled.[image]

In a portrait mode everything works fine, but in landscape I'm getting a conflict between scroll views. For example if current visible view is ScrollView2.View2 and I'm scrolling to the ScrollView1.View3, ScrollView2 scrolling as well as ScrollView1. It somehow receives the event of scrolling of ScrollView1. In result I'm getting the ScrollView2.contentOffset equal to 0.0 (but it should be equal to X of View2, for example 384.0).

Is it possible to determine which scroll is scrolling? I tried to fix with UIScrollViewDelegate methods, but didn't help me and things get even worse if I put WebViews instead of Views.

EDIT: [I have added a small sample to github](https://github.com/murderinc-/NestedUIScrollViews).

As I mentioned before, I tried to check the instance of the scrollview in "didScroll" and other delegate methods, but it's not easy to sync everything in this methods. And I tried to override hitTest methods, didn't help me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't find the way of passing the event to the right scrollview. But here is a few things that made it work:

First of all, you need to disable Paging Enabled in all nested UIScrollViews (because nested UIScrollView will be scrolled with parent UIScrollView).

Implement paging of the nested ScrollViews:

```
/*
 * User stopped dragging the innerScroll, the view is not decelerating 
 * and it is still not at its place. Lets help the view to get into right place.
 */
-(void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    if ([scrollView isEqual:innerScroll] && !decelerate) {
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.x <= view1.frame.size.width/2){
            [innerScroll scrollRectToVisible:view1.frame animated:YES];
        } else {
            [innerScroll scrollRectToVisible:view2.frame animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

/*
 * User stopped dragging the innerScroll and the View is decelerating. 
 * Lets skip an efforts of the View to get into right place and put it ourselves.
 */
- (void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ([scrollView isEqual:innerScroll]) {
        if(scrollView.contentOffset.x <= view1.frame.size.width/2){
            [innerScroll scrollRectToVisible:view1.frame animated:YES];
        } else {
            [innerScroll scrollRectToVisible:view2.frame animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

And disable and enable parent UIScrollViews while you inner UIScrollView haven't reached the last View.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if([scrollView isEqual:innerScroll]){
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollView.bounds, view1.frame)){
            if(CGRectIntersectsRect(filterScroll.bounds, view11.frame)){

            } else if(CGRectIntersectsRect(filterScroll.bounds, view22.frame)){

            }
            mainScroll.scrollEnabled = NO;
        } else if (CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollView.bounds, view2.frame)){
            mainScroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> scrollViewDidScroll:
>
> Tells the delegate when the user scrolls the
> content view within the receiver.
>
> - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

whats wrong with something like this?

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    if(scrollView == ScrollView2)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```